# Setting timeout for vertx-eventbus.js

Tags: javascript, java, timeout, sockjs, vert.x

I'm currently working on a Vertx based application that is making use of vertx-eventbus.js as described here: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sockjs_event_bus_bridge

So the client side is using vertx-eventbus.js to send a message to server side which has SockJSHandler doing the 'bridge' to receive the message. The whole mechanism has been working fine for few months. Only very recently we now potentially need to have higher timeout limit for certain messages. If run right now, those messages always cause the following warning on the server side (and also caused the eventbus to attempt to return too early on client side with "undefined"):

**Message reply handler timed out as no reply was received - it will be removed**

My question is then how do you increase the timeout for the message sending in this scenario? It seems to be using the default 30 seconds timeout and I have looked everywhere (online searches Google, here at Stackoverflow, etc) with no luck. I know there is a way to set timeout when you are sending using Vertx on the backend but not when sending from vertx-eventbus.js.

Any input is very much appreciated. Let me know if there is anything else you need to better understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Thank you,
Tom